# Where Django's cookie based session data is stored?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using Django's signed cookie engine for storing session data. My settings are:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
```

And it works as it should. Even after closing browser and web server when I visit the website, I am still logged in. I can see the sessionid being set but I can't seem to find where session data is stored. I am storing entire user object in session.

[image]

Comment: Session data is stored in the db as serialized objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is stored in the `sessionid` itself. Here's the relevant [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/61da949ff66b1e93e16ee112a5de2cf4a60ae5f3/django/contrib/sessions/backends/signed_cookies.py#L69) from the signed cookie backend:

```
def _get_session_key(self):
    """
    Instead of generating a random string, generate a secure url-safe
    base64-encoded string of data as our session key.
    """
    return signing.dumps(
        self._session, compress=True,
        salt='django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies',
        serializer=self.serializer,
    )
```